# Dealing with a tremendously popular answer that's been edited to something wrong

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

I've recently run into the accepted answer to [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator/10984975#10984975). With a score of 247 on a page that's been viewed ~19,000 times, it's a fairly important answer. The problem is that, the payload of the answer - the code snippet toward the bottom - is completely wrong, as far as I can tell (it states that dividing two integers will result in a number between 0 and 1). 
Having looked at the edit history, it seems that it's not just a technicality. The original answer went in one direction, and at some point, it was modified to a completely different direction. I don't want to revert the content for two reasons:

1. I can't tell when the votes came in relative to the edits, so I don't know how many votes each version got (therefore, I don't know if I'm "restoring" the "upvoted" answer).
2. I really don't know enough about this topic.

So what should be done in this case?

1. I flagged the answer for mod attention, but it was declined with a "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" message.
2. Adding a comment to the answer is pretty much useless - in fact, there is one there asking whether the current solution is completely wrong (as I think it is); I just barely noticed it when trying to add a comment to that effect.
3. I suppose it's possible to add an edit in the answer saying that the content has been significantly changed, but am not sure what's the etiquette on that.

Comment: /posts/id/timeline

Comment: Given the answer has been edited several times since originally posted and probably doesn't reflect the original intent of the original poster, why not just edit the post to correct what you think it wrong instead of editing to  say its wrong.

Comment: I would fix the example by using floating point instead of integer operations.

Comment: @Braiam I suppose that's an explanation on how to see the post's timeline - thanks!

Comment: Just wanna point out that I think asking on Meta was a good course of action in this case.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's why I've just upvoted - I want to encourage this kind of business I think. Would it make more sense to zip in to chat to ask about this kind of stuff though? The current answer says **what was done**, but not *how one should approach this kind of problem* (esp. if you don't have rights to do what Tunaki has done).

Comment: @Braiam: as a clickable link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10984974/timeline (for the question) and http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10984975/timeline (for the answer)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian err... [I know](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JZV8a.png)

Comment: @Braiam the link in your comment is not clickable. The links in my comments are clickable(people can click them)—there is nothing more to it.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

With the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10984975/timeline) to the rescue, I tracked down [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9745739) that introduced the code snippet you're talking about. This edit rewrote a code snippet present in the original answer with the comment

> Better formatting and removed awfully inefficient example solution

This was on October 5th, 2015. Since then, the answer has attracted 14 upvotes and 1 downvote (so its score before the edit was +234.) and no other edits.

This edit clearly conflicted with the OP's intent and should be rolled back. I took the liberty of doing just that.

Comment: I agree with you, because now the highly upvoted comments below the answer make sense again.

Comment: Do anyone have a better example of the theory, because bruteforcing doesn't look like a smart solution...

Comment: @Braiam: the theory doesn't mention brute forcing ... However (perhaps you should ask on SO!), reading this on Eternally Confuzzled: "r = rand() % N; .. only works when N evenly divides into RAND_MAX", you could try combining that with my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20327958/2564301).

Comment: @RadLexus well, the example is using bruteforcing "keep generating random numbers until you get a number"

Comment: @MartinZabel: Actually, this comment is good but its formula is wrong :( I've taken the liberty to edit the answer to add the more efficient solution that BlueRaja proposed while fixing his formula to match his explanation, hoping this will stop future readers from just switching the "improved" loop condition which actually breaks uniformity.

Comment: This is a nice example of how community moderation actually works.

Comment: Let's just be glad this was fixed before the driveby downvotes started by people who view this meta post, then the question, and instantly downvote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Is there any place that documents stuff like `/post/ID/timeline`? I completely forget it even exists, and when I remember I don't remember it was called a "timeline" or what the URL was...

Comment: @Mehrdad: /posts/timeline/id e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/timeline/10984975.  I found it by locating a post with the timeline link next to it.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/admin/links (diamond moderator privileges required)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: lol thanks, I guess that means the answer to my question is no. :P

Comment: @Mehrdad: Note that http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10984975/timeline also works, without requiring diamond mod privileges.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah I know how to get to it *now*, I was just asking if it's *documented* somewhere. (Are there other undocumented features that we should know too?)

Comment: @Mehrdad is on the unlinked (now linked) links